# How to migrate join table to entity table with liquibase without liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "id" contains null values

Tags: liquibase

I'm making the upgrade of the table that previously was just a join table to the real entity. So, it should have no primary key of ids of the entities it joins, and establish its own id. I tried this update configuration:

```
<changeSet id="20200429180824-1" author="jhipster">
    <dropPrimaryKey columnNames="teacher_id, subject_id" tableName="teacher_subject"/>
    <addColumn tableName="teacher_subject" author="jhipster">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="teacher_status" type="varchar(255)" defaultValue="APPROVED">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>

        <column name="achieved" type="datetime" defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" >
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>

        <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValue="true">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here, do not remove-->
    </addColumn>

    <dropDefaultValue tableName="teacher_subject" columnName="achieved" columnDataType="datetime"/>
</changeSet>
```

However, at the migration time I'm getting failure with this exception, despite of my expectation that the column should be just created at the moment and pre-populated with `autoIncrement` data:

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "id" contains null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I have realized the root of the problem here is in forcing "`nullable=false`". After moving it to the different and later execution of the same changeset, the migration succeed. The final changeset looks like, note separate `addNotNullConstraint` and `primaryKey`-only `<constraints primaryKey="true"/>` here:

```
<changeSet id="20200429180824-1" author="jhipster">
    <dropPrimaryKey columnNames="teacher_id, subject_id" tableName="teacher_subject"/>
    <addColumn tableName="teacher_subject" author="jhipster">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="teacher_status" type="varchar(255)" defaultValue="APPROVED">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>

        <column name="achieved" type="datetime" defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" >
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>

        <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValue="true">
            <constraints nullable="true" />
        </column>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here, do not remove-->
    </addColumn>
    <addNotNullConstraint catalogName="cat"
                          columnDataType="bigint"
                          columnName="id"
                          constraintName="teacher_subject_id_not_null"
                          tableName="teacher_subject"
                          validate="true"/>
    <dropDefaultValue tableName="teacher_subject" columnName="achieved" columnDataType="datetime"/>
</changeSet>
```